# internet explorer 10, won't show *.gif File

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

gif file which is not displayed with ie10, in firefox and any other browser it is displayed but not in ie10.

this is the Tag for the img. I'm using MVC3 with C#:

```
<img class="topBanner" src="@Url.Content(@Settings.Default.BannerFolderPath + "/TopBanner.gif")" alt="" />
```

the banner can be downloaded here: http://ul.to/il49d8xh

if i open file with a image viewer, it is shown, but with ie8 just the red cross.

Comment: What is the generated markup for the image tag in IE10?

Comment: Your title, text, and tags are mixing IE10 and IE8.  Which is it?